# Restore RAM data from week ago

Tags: windows, memory, buffer, xbox-game-dvr

I would like to know if it is possible to restore Data from a certain of time (week ago). I want to get to buffer of windows dvr clip which record last 30 seconds and make clip from it... 
It looks impossible, but maybe one of you will know somethhing.

Comment: Definitely impossible. Even if whatever you want to retrieve left the memory seconds ago, you cannot get it back. That's simply not how memory works. If the program uses a cache file on disk, then maybe, but even then, a week is a long time.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible. Your operating system will long ago have replaced what you are looking for with something else, even if you never rebooted.